# bootstrap thumbnail slider very slow loading in pop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi i'm new in web development. I'm finding solution for my problem since last two days, but did not find any good solution. Actually i need thumbnail slider in pop. I have tried  [this one](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html) but it is loading very slow. Please view the image and guide me which slider i should use.

[image]

Comment: use small thumbnail images that load faster

Comment: I tried it but still facing same issue

Comment: how large are your img?

Comment: 400 x 400 is the size of image